# SharePoint Edit Tasklist Task

Tags: list, sharepoint, task, edit

I have SharePoint setup, and for a test I added a Task List, added a few columns, and tested it out.  I wanted to modify the task list task page, not the task list page.  I can edit the task list page, but I cannot edit the task list task page.  I am missing the Edit Page button from site actions on that page.  How can I edit the page of the actual task?

Answer (score 0):

Not out of the box.  Other than generating a different view, there isn't much you can do to the listing page.  Perhaps you can expose the list via a Content Query Web Part and format it how you like.